# Samsung Galaxy Tab S 8.4 (SM-T700) support for OTG (On-The-Go)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, usb-on-the-go

Not having any luck determining if I can see/move files from my camera to my T700 using a On-The-Go adapter/cable.

See cables advertised but read on various sources that not all devices support all Host services.  Not having much luck finding a cable locally so before I go through the trouble of getting one on line, finding it does not work and having to return it, I'm look for assistance in determining if the T700 is likely to support Host/OTG services.  Contacted Samsung but they just told me none of the tablets support OTG - interesting, who's buying all those adapters/cables that won't work?

Sometimes I feel like I'm the only one who bought a Galaxy Tab S 8.4 as I never find any mention of this tablet on forums I look on.  Am I the only one? :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a USB OTG cable at Best Buy.  Samsung branded as a "Host" cable but nobody knew how it works (or even they had it - 'OTG' that is).  Tried to convince me I need to swap SD cards to transfer pictures from camera to tablet.

Not buying this, I bought the Samsung "Host" adapter cable on the assurance I could return it if it didn't work.  It did.  Worked great.  Just plug in the cable to both the camera and tablet and power up the camera.  And there is, identified as usb a.  Was able to view and transfer (copy) pictures and videos from the camera to the tablet.  No separate file manager app needed either.